# error in displaying data from specific XML tags in a file?

Tags: asp.net, xml

```
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("D://project_elysian//data.xml");

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            reader.Read();
            //Response.Write(reader.Value + "</br>");
            //Response.Write(reader.Depth);

            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case "Id": Response.Write(reader.Value + "</br>");
                    break;
                case "Name": Response.Write(reader.Value + "</br>");
                    break;       
            }
        }    
    }
```

I am trying to read data.xml file and display its contents of the specified tags, but the resultant page remains blank, and no compilation error is given, am stuck, can't figure out what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is working outside switch, I guess than name of the node is of different case.Check the case of the nodes

Edit:

You are calling reader.read() twice and the reader.value will not return proper value for an element.

If you still want to use xmlreader check the below code

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(<XML Path>)
    while (reader.Read())     
    {         if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)      
             {      
                switch (reader.Name)           
                {
                    case "Id": Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(reader.ReadString()) + "</br>");        
                        break;
                    case "Name": Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(reader.ReadString()) + "</br>");                 
                        break;          
                }      
            }

    }

    reader.Close();
```

Comment: the cases of the nodes and the names of the tags are the same, indeed I repeatedly copied and pasted them to make sure they are the same

Answer (score 2):

I suspect if you "View Source" on the resulting page you'll see the data you are expecting to see.

The problem is that your web browser sees these xml elements as unknown html tags and so doesn't know how to display them.

You need to "encode" your output, so your string is literally displayed as is.

Instead of writing:

```
Response.Write(reader.Value + "</br>");
```

try

```
Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(reader.Value) + "</br>");
```

What this does is replace < with &lt; > with &gt; and a few others. "&lt;" tells the browser to render "<" rather than treat it as the beginning of a tag.

[**Edit** - in response to comment]

It sounds like your none of your cases are ever true. Without knowing the contents of the source xml file, it is hard to say - but have you tried putting a breakpoint on the Response.Writes in the cases? Are they ever hit?

If not, then this is not related to anything I mentioned above - but you are not getting what you expect from your reader.

Try starting with a small sample of the xml file and step through in the debugger. Try and determine what data (e.g. the reader.Name property) is present on the reader when you hit something you are interested in, and amend the switch statement accordingly.

[**2nd Edit** - in response to sample xml]

Your mistake is the `Read()` call just after the check for the `XmlNodeType.Element`. You are basically reading until you find an element (the `Read()` call in the while). Once you've found the element, you are then *pushing past the element* (the other `Read()` call) before trying to read the element name. This inner `reader.Read()` makes sure you are no longer on the element by the time you try to check its name.

Try this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        // Capture the element name before pushing past it.
        var elementName = reader.Name;

        reader.Read();
        //Response.Write(reader.Value + "</br>");
        //Response.Write(reader.Depth);

        switch (elementName)
        {
            case "Id": 
                Response.Write(reader.Value);
                break;
            case "Name":
                Response.Write(reader.Value);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The key to finding this sort of thing, is to debug carefully. Start with a cut down xml file and either actually step through in the debugger, or write debug output to a log or the response. It'll make identifying these sort of issues much easier.

Comment: i see ` <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTE5NjgzNzQzMA9kFgICAQ9kFgICAw8WAh4LXyFJdGVtQ291bnRmZGTSDrrn32COom4hBY/Fe2QBKmIAusjuF7trYLYzsX6HzA==" />

</div> `

in the page source along with other HTML tags

**and when I remove the switch case statement and uncomment the two commented Response.Write statements they work perfectly and display all the nodes data each in a separate line**

EDIT: ** `Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(reader.Value) + "</br>"); ` this isn't working either, everything still the same**

Comment: the sample XML file link is given in the main question [click here](http://support.propertybase.com/entries/441730-weblisting) for the link

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you take a look at XML (de)serialization instead of using XmlReader. .Net will verify the xml and you will more easily be able to debug the Xml input.

You simply create a class with fields mirroring your Xml structure and use the following code:

```
class searchResult
{

   public List<item> itemList { get; set;}
}
```

A complex field class example

```
class item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

The actual work gets done like so:

```
   XmlSerializer SerializerIn = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerializeTest));
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    SerializeTest loadTest = (SerializeTest)SerializerIn.Deserialize(fs);
    fs.Close();
```

Where SerializeTest is the class your loading the xml into. It is much easier to work this way, because you never need to deal with the raw Xml unless it is invalid.

You can find more info here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4491/Load-and-save-objects-to-XML-using-serialization
Probably a better tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113423/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/012302-1.shtml

Comment: so should I place the nested child nodes as nested classes inside this SerializeTest (root) class?

Comment: If they are complex types they only need a property of that type for nesting.

Comment: all of the nodes are plain text nodes, as you can see the sample XML file [here](http://support.propertybase.com/entries/441730-weblisting)

Comment: I've updated the example. You can use any nested plain objects. .Net will figure out how the serialization works. You can even use collections.

Comment: Ive made it look a little more like your Xml. It is incomplete though. This is for processing the response.

Comment: it'd be very helpful if you can point me in a direction towards collections, as I think foreach loop will be good for this kinda problem